# Play Framework 2.1 - Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am calling a webservice like this:

```
WS
  .url(url)
  .get
  .map { response => // error occurs on this line
    response.status match {
      case 200 => Right(response.json)
      case status => Left(s"Problem accessing api, status '$status'")
  }
}
```

The complete error: `Error: Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext, either require one yourself or import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

According to [this issue](http://web.archive.org/web/20140222113140/http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/899-error-cannot-find-an-implicit-executioncontext-either-require-one-yourself-or-import-executioncontextimplicitsglobal), it is fixed in the documentation. I needed to add the following import:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
```

Comment: About the execution context. Some people think it's the same thing as the Scala global context. It however is not.

[Execution.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/concurrent/Execution.scala) is pointing to [Invoker.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/system/Invoker.scala?source=cc)

So it actually is the execution context of the Play actor system. This allows you to change behavior using the application.conf

Comment: The "This issue" link is broken now. There is an archive on the web.archive though: http://web.archive.org/web/20140222113140/http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/899-error-cannot-find-an-implicit-executioncontext-either-require-one-yourself-or-import-executioncontextimplicitsglobal

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg Thank you, I have adjusted the link

Comment: link broken again

Comment: @dlite922 Thanks for reporting. Too bad the internet does not have persistent links.

Comment: I'd say it's more correct to inject it from the injection framework as indicated below. particularly given that this is the way the example apps manage it.

Comment: Since play 2.6 you should use Guice dependency injection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961708/play-framework-2-1-cannot-find-an-implicit-executioncontext/37264750#37264750

Answer (score 2):

Since Play 2.6 it's recommended to use guice dependency injection for `execution context`.

**Default execution context injection:**

*Foo.scala*

```
class Foo @Inject()()(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) {

def bar() = {
   WS.url(url)
     .get
     .map { response => // error occurs on this line
       response.status match {
         case 200 => Right(response.json)
         case status => Left(s"Problem accessing api, status '$status'")
     }
   }
}
```

**Custom execution context injection:**

*application.conf*

```
# db connections = ((physical_core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)
fixedConnectionPool = 9

database.dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

*DatabaseExecutionContext.scala*

```
@Singleton 
class DatabaseExecutionContext @Inject()(system: ActorSystem) extends CustomExecutionContext(system,"database.dispatcher")
```

*Foo.scala*

```
class Foo @Inject()(implicit executionContext: DatabaseExecutionContext ) {   ...    }
```

**More info at:**

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution-is-deprecated
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26#CustomExecutionContext-and-Thread-Pool-Sizing

Comment: Your code does not inject the execution context. It still uses implicit resolution to get the execution context.

Comment: As per Play documentation (at least 2.6), @mgosk's answer is the standard; see: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools#Using-the-default-thread-pool

Comment: There is, however, more to it. You can extend/define `CustomExecutionContext` too. See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution-is-deprecated and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26#CustomExecutionContext-and-Thread-Pool-Sizing