# trying to implement load schema using silhouette play 2.4 play-slick 1.0.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0, silhouette

I'm trying to make some little improvements to play-silhouette-seed sample with the purpose of avoiding manually creation of tables in postgres. I tried to follow the implementation used in

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/computer-database

, but I'm having some issues with injection when I add a bind(classOf[InitialData]).asEagerSingleton() to a InitialData class. I get: Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application. I uploaded the tentative app in

https://github.com/renexdev/Play-Auth-Slick-Seed-Load-Schema

. I modified some methods in UserImpl.scala but the important file is the /app/modules/InitialData.scala which is called by the  Abstract Module in a bind(classOf[InitialData]).asEagerSingleton() when app starts.
I was suggested to pass an execution context to the initialData class. I tried the 
def doSomething(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
suggested in

https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md

and the import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
suggested in

[Play Framework 2.1 - Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961708/play-framework-2-1-cannot-find-an-implicit-executioncontext)

but without success. I would appreciate if anyone could give me some insights on what could be wrong with the injection or with the constructor. Thanks for your time.
ReneX

Answer (score 1):

If you bind a class as eager singleton you must pay attention that your code doesn't reference a static `play.api.Play.current` call. The Guice bindings are wired before a Play application gets started and the instance you bind as eager singleton will also be instantiated before the application starts. So if you reference a started application in this code you see the error "There is no started application".

The problem in your code is the that the `DAOSlick` trait creates the `DatabaseConfig` statically with the help of the static referenced `play.api.Play.current`. You should inject the `DatabaseConfigProvider` or the `DatabaseConfig` instance into your DAO implementations. Please look at the [Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick#Usage) how this should be done.

Comment: Thks again for your comments Akkie! A+